# spark standalone-mode pass spark.driver.extraJavaOptions

Tags: apache-spark

My application connects to a spark cluster (just starting a master and some slaves, not used yarn), now it throws StackOverwflowErr for ObjectInputStream, so i should increase -Xss of driver and executor.
The documents said you can't change driver properties in your application code (using sparkConf).

changing spark-defaults.conf not worked (i guesss it only works with spark-submit)
So how should i change driver related configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used:
conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions","-Xss4m") in my java code and now spark executor run with xss=4m. I was biased with this part of spark documentation:

> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the
>   SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has
>   already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the
>   --driver-java-options command line option or in your default properties file.